# Mapping port in docker / docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a similar issue but the suggested answer does not seems to work for me. My problem is that I want to split an app on multiple containers. One of the components is willing to connect to a local redis (which I have now moved in its own container)

```
version: '3'

services:

  server-test:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-cli -h redis-db ping

  redis-db:
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

works fine - but I want something along this line:

```
version: '3'

services:

  server-test:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-cli ping

  redis-db:
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

I have tried to add the lines:

```
ports:
  - "6379:redis-db:6379"
```

but I end up with this error message:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.server-test.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

Any idea ?

And btw it seems that the expose is not even needed in my first case.

Comment: What do you want that [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) line to do?  Where are you putting it in the file?  (And yes, `expose:` in a `docker-compose.yml` file doesn't really do anything at all.)

Comment: I was expecting `compose` to wire me port `6379` on container `server-test` to port `6379` on `redis-db`. May be I need to run `netcat` on `server-test`

Comment: You don't need to do anything for inter-container communication to work; if you do specify `ports:`, they get ignored for this case.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the overall setup a little more.

Comment: My second example (the one I need) does not work because nothing is listening on port `6379` ... This is why I mentioned `netcat`

Comment: The `redis` Docker Hub image should listen on port 6379 by default, but you do need to give the `redis-cli` client a host name – it is not the default `localhost` ("this container").